# The meaning(s) of 차돌?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I heard this sentence today '따님을 차돌같이 잘 키우셨어요'. I've only ever know 차돌 being a type of meat, but looking around on the internet I've found several more meaning of this word including 'quartz', 'marble' and 'shrewd person'. I can only assume that in this example the person was referring to the latter, but can I check if 차돌 has these meanings and if '차돌같이' is used often as 'set phrase'? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'따님을 차돌같이 잘 키우셨어요' In this sentence, the meaning of 차돌(chadol) is

1. The man of firm[steady](on the good side) character
2. The man who always prepares something and can hardly do mistake

'차돌' is not commonly used. It is very old expression. :)

But if someone uses this word, it will look very smart(The man have good vocabulary).

Comment: If someone uses this expression, I would think they are not smart but just very old. I can't imagine anyone under 60 using this expression.